# Canvas gets larger every time I use it to create a chart

Tags: html, canvas, charts, html5-canvas

I'm currently using Chart.JS on Phonegap and every time I make a new chart on the same Canvas, it gets twice as big. It's very strange and I don't know if I'm describing it properly. I'll clarify upon suggestions/questions, thanks guys.

Here is the javascript used to make the chart:

```
var ctx = $("#myChart").get(0).getContext("2d");
ctx.clearRect(0,0,ctx.canvas.width,ctx.canvas.height);
new Chart(ctx).Pie(data); 
canvas.width = canvas.width
```

EDIT:
I don't know why this bug happens, but I fixed it by hard-setting the width and height each time:

```
var ctx = $("#myChart").get(0).getContext("2d");

// set canvas dimensions
ctx.canvas.width = chartWidth;
ctx.canvas.height = chartHeight;

// draw chart
ctx.clearRect(0,0,ctx.canvas.width,ctx.canvas.height);
drawChart(avgMin[1],avgMin[0], ctx);

// maintain canvas dimensions
ctx.canvas.width = chartWidth;
ctx.canvas.height = chartHeight;
```

Comment: What´s the meaning of canvas.width = canvas.width ?

Comment: It's a way to reset the canvas size from what I've read.

Comment: `canvas.width = canvas.width` does exactly the same as `ctx.clearRect(0,0,ctx.canvas.width,ctx.canvas.height);`, which is clearing the whole canvas.